# Typescript Intellisense not working when using @ path root directory imports

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, next.js, intellisense

I have run into an issue where TypeScript/Intellisense cannot determine types when importing using @ symbol in my compilerOptions set to my root directory:

[image]

Using ../ I can see types clearly:

[image]

I set compilerOptions parameters as follows, first in tsconfig.json and later i created a jsconfig.json file and set them there as well:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["/src/*"]
    }
```

I've updated /src/* to ./src/* and src/* with no success.  To be clear the site still runs without issue, but i have lost the ability to take advantage of intellisense and typescript.  Please advise, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The file was a .jsx ... yea i did lose a whole day to that but changing to .tsx worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following in your `settings.json` file and it will resolve your problem:

```
"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "project-relative",
```